# Real integral evaluates to imaginary number

Tags: numerical-integration

The following integral:`Integrate[Exp[-2/3 Log[1 + x^3]], {x, 0, 1}]` is evaluating to an imaginary number. Its closed-form expression should be `(2^(-2/3) Gamma[1/3] Gamma[7/6])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]`

How can I get Mathematica to produce this expression? (I need a closed form at another point, where I can't guess the actual value.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting an imaginary number because you're using integers.

```
Integrate[Exp[-2./3. Log[1. + x^3.]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

(*
0.883319
*)

Also:

```
Integrate[Exp[-a Log[1 + x^3]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

(*
Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, a, 4/3, -1]
*)

You can then replace *a* by $2/3$:

```
Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, a, 4/3, -1] /. a -> 2/3
```

$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$

Comment: Or use `NIntegrate`: `NIntegrate[Exp[-2/3 Log[1 + x^3]], {x, 0, 1}]` gives `0.883319`

Comment: I need the exact form, not approximate.

Answer (score 3):

We can see why this happens looking at the indefinte integral:

```
 indef = Integrate[Exp[-2/3 Log[1 + x^3]], x]
```

> analytic expression involving `Hypergeometric2F1`

This expression changes character and picks up an imaginary component right at 1:

```
 Plot[{ Re[indef ], Im[indef ]}, {x, 0, 1.3}]
```

[image]

Evaluating the definite integral using the left value at 1 we get the correct result:

```
 ( indef /. x -> 0.9999 ) - ( indef /. x -> 0 ) // Chop
```

> 0.883256

now we can get there like this as well:

```
 Integrate[Exp[-2/3 Log[1 + x^3]], {x, 0, 1 - 10^-8}] // N // Chop
```